# R Studio - How to add count of values in another column in next 7 days?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that is a list of dates, followed by a column that either contains "R" for regular or "S" for special:

```
date <- c('01/01', '01/02', '01/03', '01/04', '01/05', '01/06', '01/07', '01/08', '01/09')

day <- c('S', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'R', 'S', 'R', 'R', 'S')

data <- data.frame(date, day)

It looks like this: 

date . . . day

01/01. . . S

01/02. . . S

01/03. . . R

01/04. . . S

01/05. . . R

01/06. . . S

01/07. . . R

01/08. . . R

01/09. . . S

....
```

I'm trying to add a column now to indicate how many "special" days are coming up in the next 7 days, based on the date. For example, for 01/01, this column should say 3, since from 01/02 to 01/08, there are 3 "S" days (01/02, 01/04, and 01/06).

I'm trying to use mutate, but I'm not quite sure how to make this work. Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you could present your data as a data frame object so making your question reproducible. Are the dates in the dates column always in sequence?

Comment: Yes, the dates are always in sequence! I added that to the original (I believe, is that what you meant?), thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Kathy your initial post showed the 'Date' in a different format i.e. month/day/year.  I posted a solution based on that only

Comment: Just use `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` and paste the result to your question.

Comment: Sorry, was reformatting while you were answering - your solution works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could convert the 'Date' column to `Date` class, loop over the 'Date', create a logical index with `between` with the 'Date' column and each element of 'Date' and 7 days later along with the logical vector where 'Day' is 'S', get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")   
df1 %>% 
   mutate(nspecial = map_int(Date, ~ 
       sum(df1$Day == 'S' & between(df1$Date, .x + days(1), .x + days(7)))))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
sapply(df1$Date, function(x) sum(df1$Day == 'S' & 
          df1$Date > x & df1$Date <= (x + 7)))
#[1] 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("01/01/2012", "01/02/2012", "01/03/2012", 
"01/04/2012", "01/05/2012", "01/06/2012", "01/07/2012", "01/08/2012", 
"01/09/2012"), Day = c("S", "S", "R", "S", "R", "S", "R", "R", 
"S")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I like your solution. I think it should be polished a little to give exactly what is in the question for future visitors. The expectation was to return 3 for 01/01 since from 01/02 to 01/08, there are 3 "S" days. Then we should check from day + 1, like `df1 %>% mutate(nspecial = map_int(Date, ~sum(df1$Day == 'S' & between(df1$Date, .x + days(1), .x + days(7)))))`.